# Determine if Macbook Pro hard drive is damaged or repairable

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, partition, ssd, hardware

I have a 2019 16" MacBook Pro with 512GB drive which I would like to reformat and dual boot with Ubuntu. (I'm ok with a stable MacOS or Ubuntu single-boot too). There is no data on it that needs to be saved.

There seems to be an issue with the hard drive, and I'm trying to work out whether reformatting from scratch would fix it, or if there is an underlying hardware issue.

It has had a problem for a while where occasionally (~once per day) it will just instantly power off (even while connected to power). A brief flurry of fan noise, then off.

I ran First Aid on the main volume `Macintosh HD - Data` and it reported:

- error: omap entry, invaild ok_xid
- Object map is invalid
- The volume `/dev/rdisk1s1` could not be verified completely.
- File system verify or repair failed (-69845)

First Aid on the `APPLE SSD AP0512N Media` was fine.

First Aid on `Container disk1` reported similarly an invalid Object map, with error -69716.

First Aid on `Macintosh HD` was fine.

Because of these errors (-69716 again), Disk Utility would not allow re-partitioning the drive.

I tried to use Recovery to repair the drive, but it was unable.

I then re-installed Big Sur from Recovery, which worked, but again reported an error with the disk (I didn't note the details).

### Next steps?

I understand the SSD is soldered in, so replacing it is not trivial.

So:

- is there a more drastic way of reformatting the drive that I can try?
- is there a way to tell definitively if there is a hardware failure here?
- if there is a failed hard drive, are there any options besides taking the machine to Apple support, or running Ubuntu from an external drive?

Comment: I would start with a fresh install of macOS before going down the Linux route whether solo or bootcamp.  However, I am concerned that you might have a physical issue because a file system error shouldn’t turn off your MacBook.  If you do a clean reinstall and the issue persists, you’ll want to take it in for service. There are places that do board level repair that will change out the nand storage chips for (usually) less than what Apple charges.